# Prevent Scala from parsing XML

Tags: xml, scala, parsing

I would like to define a function with this symbolic name without using backticks :

```
def <? (i: Int): Unit = println(i)
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error `identifier expected but $XMLSTART$< found`. Is there a way to prevent Scala from parsing this symbolic name as XML ?

Thanks !

Comment: I thought xml was moved out of the core library as of [Scala 2.11](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1) but when testing it in the REPL with 2.11.5 it's still trying to parse xml as you are finding.

Comment: I thought the same. I was thus wondering if there were some annotation to prevent this.

Comment: And it will likely never be moved out, I guess, from what I've read here: http://www.quora.com/Will-Scala-ever-remove-XML-literals

Comment: That post was made before the announcement in 2.11 that XML would be moved out of the core library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not.

Unfortunately you'll have to escape it every time with backsticks.

```
def `<?` (i: Int): Unit = println(i)
```

Testing it:

```
scala> def `<?` (i: Int): Unit = println(i)
$less$qmark: (i: Int)Unit

scala> `<?`(3)
3
```

Comment: The OP specifically says he wants to do this without backticks.

Comment: Big oops. I have missed that.